# Fixed-width, flexible-height css grid

Tags: html, css, css-float

**NOTE** This is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584345/fixed-width-variable-height-grid-css), however there is a strict no-javascript requirement and the answer should be responsive (i.e there is not a fixed number of columns).

I would like to style several fixed width, variable height boxes using no javascript such that they form a kind of fluid grid.  This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f87pnwm2/) yields the picture below.  This is essentially just the following css:

```
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 150px;
}
```

[image: boxes]

I'd like for the only vertical empty space to be the margins.  In terms of the screenshot above, I'd like for the tops of `5` and `6` to move upwards to 1em from the bottom of `1` and `2`, respectively.

Comment: I am assuming that you do not know how many blocks there might be or the height of each, or both. The nature of `float:left` is not going to allow for your desired result without the ability to calculate the block height and respond to it. ie. jQuery/js

Comment: I'm not aware of **any** non-js solutions to this issue...even `flexbox` (AFAIK) doesn't offer any help here. That's why the JS solutions are so popular.

Comment: Using flexbox, I guess there's [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f87pnwm2/4/).  But yeah it doesn't quite cut it.

Comment: Using column-count, there's [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f87pnwm2/3/).  But that assumes a fixed width of the columns.  It would be nice to have something more flexible.

Answer (score -3):

it's not possible by using pure CSS because any how you have to know the current position of div so if you really wanna do this then you have to re position the `<div>` either using " margin-top " property of css or using jQuery like these jqueryhouse.com/jquery-grid-plugins